# SQL Server 2012 - SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have VS2012 Ultimate installed. In the Installed products it states I have SQL Server Data Tools 11.1. When I go to SQL Server 2012 and click on the SQL Server Data Tools Menu option, VS2010 starts up.

I changed the target to point to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

So now VS2012 starts up but under new projects I DO NOT have the option to create a new SSIS package. Nor the option to download the data tools off the web.

I did go through VS2010 and download DataTools for 2010 and also selected the download for 2012. VS2010 now has Business Intelligence but VS2012 still does not have this template.

Please help.  Slowly going mad.

Comment: **SQL Server Data Tools** and **Business Intelligence** are not the same thing - which one is it that you want/need?

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server Data Tools part for Business Intelligence (SSAS, SSIS, SSRS) has been released as an add-on for Visual Studio 2012 in March 2013.

It can be downloaded [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2013/03/06/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2012-released-online.aspx)

If you are running on a 64 bit system and have any error message, use option 1 during the installation (New install). It will only add the BI Studio and not try to reinstall anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Cnfusingly Microsoft have 2 different products called SQL server data tools, the one from the installation media which gives you the BI templates in VS2010 and one that you can download, which just adds the database project type to VS2010/12.  Currently there are no BI templates available for VS2012, which is incredibly frustrating, it's due to the version of the Visual Studio Shell used by the tools on the installer only supporting 2010.  I guess we'll just have to wait for an update to that :(

Comment: OMG.  Why don't they mention this part in their msdn documentation.

Comment: Yep, confusing isn't it.  I ran into the exact same problem, this [link](http://blog.wakebi.com/2012/08/sql-server-2012-database-projects.html) explains the differences and was the first post that I saw that explained what was going on.

Comment: This is extremely useful information. I don't know what MS gets out of confusing its market!

Answer (score 0):

New download and more compatibility languages as of January 2019.

[SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Supported Operating Systems:

- Windows 10 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 8, 8.1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows Server 2012 (x64), R2 (x64)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)